# Regex replace for multiple matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to figure out a Regex to inject and remove a string (in this case `var.par_`) at the following locations:

- Very Beginning
- After ^
- After ^OR

Example input string when injecting:

```
job=developer^language=js^ORlanguage=react^ORlanguageSTARTSWITHjava
```

Should result in output of

```
var.par_job=developer^var.par_language=js^ORvar.par_language=react^ORvar.par_languageSTARTSWITHjava
```

---

and vice versa when removing:

```
var.par_language=react^ORvar.par_languageSTARTSWITHjava
```

should result in

```
language=react^ORlanguageSTARTSWITHjava
```

My current feeble attempt was this:

```
var input = "job=developer^language=js^ORlanguage=react^ORlanguageSTARTSWITHjava";


const replaceToken = "var.par_";


var output = input.replace(/^()?/, replaceToken).replace(/\^()?/g, '^' + replaceToken);
```

Comment: You can match those locations with `(^|\^OR|\^)`

Comment: Added my current attempt barman

Comment: What's the point of the empty group `()?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let input = "job=developer^language=js^ORlanguage=react^ORlanguageSTARTSWITHjava";
const replaceToken = "var.par_";
let output = input.replace(/^|\^OR|\^/g, '$&' + replaceToken);
console.log(output)
```

The regexp `/^|\^OR|\^/` matches each of your locations. `$&` in the replacement gets replaced with the match. So there's no need to use multiple calls to `.replace()`.

Comment: Honestly I thought I tried that combo with the pipe and was getting no luck. Maybe it was an errant typo, but thank you. Also I called you the incorrect name, so I apologize.

Comment: You're not the first. But there's automatic name completion after `@`, you should use that.